# Is there any way to download('make available offline') an SPTrack/SPAlbum without it being in a Playlist?

Tags: ios, spotify, libspotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

This is just a very basical question, because I try to implement a library in my app. So is there any way to `download('make available offline')` an SPTrack/SPAlbum without it being in a Playlist and if yes, how?

Will I have to make a kind of 'Library' playlist and sync it using that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not — you need to make a playlist to offline sync items.